# Set facebook application locale based on user's facebook language settings

Tags: facebook, facebooker

So if i am French and browse facebook in French, is it possible for an application to change its locale or language settings based on that of the user? In other words, if i open the facebook app, i would like to see the app content in French. Similarly for any other language. How can this be done?

P.S. I am using the old REST api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a couple of ways to do this:

1) Check for locale in facebook params when the app loads, in particular the "fb_sig_locale" parameter

2) Use fql on user table like so:

```
select locale from user where uid = '1100100101'
```

Answer (score 0):

setup a `before_filter` like this (I'm assuming You're using `I18n` to store the current locale) :

```
  if request_comes_from_facebook?
    # e.g. "fb_sig_locale"=>"en_US" or "fb_sig_locale"=>"de_DE"
    if fb_locale = params[:fb_sig_locale]
      I18n.locale = fb_locale.sub('_', '-')
    else
      logger.info ":fb_sig_locale parameter not found in request"
    end
  end
```